# How can I open a webpage with post parameters and headers in Microsoft Edge?

Tags: c#, winforms

Internet Explorer 11 will be retired in June 2022, so I substitute Edge for Internet Explorer 11.

I used the COM object to open a webpage with post paramters and headers in Internet Explorer 11.

But I don't know how I can do this in Microsoft Edge.

```
string param = "userid=xxxx;password=yyyy" ;    // POST DATA

object oUrl = "http://www.xxxx.com";
object flags = new object();
object targetFramName = new object();
object vPost = encode.GetBytes(param);
object vHeaders = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=" + UTF8Encoding.UTF8.WebName + "\r\n";

SHDocVw.InternetExplorer ie = new SHDocVw.InternetExplorer();

ie.AddressBar   = true;
ie.MenuBar      = false;
ie.StatusBar    = true;
ie.ToolBar      = 0

ie.Navigate2(ref oUrl, ref flags, ref targetFramName, ref vPost, ref vHeaders);
ie.Visible = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that we could use the `CoreWebView2_WebResourceRequested` event:

```
e.Request.Method = "POST";

e.Request.Content = new MemoryStream(postdata);

e.Request.Headers ....
```

But we have a new API available for this scenario, `CoreWebView2.NavigateWithWebResourceRequest` (requires SDK 1.0.707-prerelease). I recommend trying this to see if it works for you.

Comment: I must open Edge Browser ( With POST DATA ) in my applications.